# div centered vertically with specific margin when resize

Tags: javascript, vertical-alignment, centering, margins

I really need some help.

I have this test-web: www.sfrpsicologia.com/inicio.html

As you can see, I have centered the green box in the middle of the screen. The problem is that when I resize the height of the window, this box is above the logo and the footer. And what I want is that ALWAYS this div respect the height of the logo and the footer. I need a margin top and bottom that this box never overpass.

Any help please? I dont know much about javascript. I have tried with css styles but as it is positioned absolutely I cant do it.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use absolute positioning in this case.
You are trying to solve poor design problem with javascript and that's not a good practise.
Use sticky footer approach http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/
and overthink your page structure based on that technique.

---

OK I got what you meant.

Do this , however I don't guarantee it will work because I can't test it on your site but it's supposed to if any obstacles occure you should modify it to work.
I'm useing jQuery you should be familiar with it.

So **step 1**(get the div) `<div id=wrapp>` and take it's height

```
var wrapp = jQuery('#wrapp');
var h = wrapp.outerHeight();
```

**step 2**(Set some other variables)

```
var winH = 0;
var pos = null;
var footerH = 34;
var headerH = 74;
```

These heights are the elements besides your `<div id=wrapp>` in your case they might be a few more or less.

```
var footerH = 34;
var headerH = 74;
```

The idea is when there's no room for all of them on the screen stop `<div id=wrapp>` from going upwards.

**step 3** (All this is bind to window resize event):

```
jQuery(window).resize(function(){

    winH = jQuery(this).height();
    pos = wrapp.position();    
    if(winH  < h + headerH + footerH  )
        wrapp.css({'top' : pos.top});
    else
        wrapp.css({'top' : '50%'});
});
```

Update window height on resize, also get `<div id=wrapp>` position object
and if(there's no more room according to all the heights you put) fix the `top` position to **current top position of** `<div id=wrapp>` else put it back to percentage.

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/F7mrf/44/

If you got the idea with very little modifications it should work, you'll just have to do the math and put the right numbers, good luck

Comment: The problem is that I dont use position absolute because of the whole functionality of the page. Not to place the logo and the footer.

Comment: That's brilliant. I have managed to do it thanks to you. Many many thanks

Comment: I saw your modifications on the website.
Don't fix it to 318px but make it variable pos.top like in the example. If someone has bigger monitor there will be a jump of the div. Because his 50% won't reach 318px.

Comment: I have tried to make it as in the example and I have an erro in the console because It finds an unexpected token error. But you are right, I would need not to fix it because now I am including some media querie and when I change the #wrapp height to 600px in larger monitors I don't have what I expected... Do you know why is this unexpected token error? And what I can't get it is the same with the bottom... It still overlap this part. Many thanks for your time

Comment: Well you've missed a bracket or semicolon or worse you're missing that definition `pos = wrapp.position();` .

Comment: I have already changed it. But, as the #wrapp height changes 100px when the window width is resized, it doesn't really works. And I don't know why but when the window height is resized really fast it doesn't work either.

Many thanks kidwon